# javascript audio API -- analyze audio file to detect exact sounds, for lip syncing

Tags: javascript, audio, real-time, html5-audio

I've seen things like [waveform.js](https://github.com/bbc/waveform-data.js#f=2) which uses the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) to display waveform data, and there are many other tools out there which are able to analyze the exact sound points of an audio file in JavaScript.

If so, it should be possible to use this power of analyzation to use for real-time lip syncing using JavaScript, i.e., to get an animated character to speak at the same time the user is speaking, by simply using an audio context, and reading the data-points some how to find the right sounds.

So the question becomes, more specifically:

**How exactly do I analyze audio data to extract what exact sounds are made at specific timestamps?**

I want to get the end result of something like [Rhubarb Lip Sync](https://github.com/DanielSWolf/rhubarb-lip-sync), except with JavaScript, and in real time. It doesn't have to be exact, but as close as possible.

Comment: can you share any links about that topic? I am definitely curious. This sounds like a security nightmare to me if its true.

Comment: sounds like you want [Tensorflow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/transfer/audio_recognizer) they already have a [tutorial to do with audio](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/speech-commands) - so probably worth having a look.

Comment: @timur it appears this only works with a very specific set of words, from the docs (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/speech-commands): 


"Currently, the supported vocabularies are:

'18w' (default): The 20 item vocaulbary, consisting of: 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'go', 'stop', 'yes', and 'no', in addition to 'background_noise' and 'unknown'.
'directional4w': The four directional words: 'up', 'down', 'left', and 'right', in addition to 'background_noise' and 'unknown'."

Comment: @timur any idea how to do something similar with all words / sounds?

Comment: Yes, you will have to train your own model

Comment: [train it for all 15831 syllables?](http://web.archive.org/web/20160822211027/http://semarch.linguistics.fas.nyu.edu/barker/Syllables/index.txt) Is there some kind of better way , or is there a complete trained model available for download? If not is there any way to simply analyze the sound data to try to detect the syllables without using machine learning?

Comment: I would go with [36 phonemes](https://www.eupedia.com/linguistics/number_of_phonemes_in_european_languages.shtml) and try to catch them. That would in my understanding be a 36 item vocabulary.

Comment: And here [a phoneme collection of only 10 possible phonemes](http://www.garycmartin.com/mouth_shapes.html).

Answer (score 4):

There is no algorithm that allows you to detect phonemes correctly 100% of the time.

You didn't say whether this was for real-time use or for offline use, but that would strongly affect which algorithm you'd use.

An algorithm based on mel frequency cepstral coefficients would be expected to give you about 80% accuracy, which would be good enough for video games or the like.

Deep learning systems based on covolutional neural nets would give you excellent recognition, but they are not real time systems (yet).

You could maybe start with [Meyda](https://meyda.js.org/audio-features), for example, and compare the audio features of the signal you're listening to, with a human-cataloged library of audio features for each phoneme.

Comment: preferably  real time, like adobe animate

Comment: also are there any examples of how to do this in javascript to get the timestamps of each sound for lipsync data?

Comment: u still they  r?